# IOS UICollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths crash when header is on screen

Tags: ios, crash, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` with a header of size non-zero. It seems whenever `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` is called, if the header is on screen, the program crashes with the following message:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: <_UICollectionViewItemKey: 0xa38c910> Type = SV Kind = UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader IndexPath = <NSIndexPath 0xa38c7c0> 2 indexes [0, 0])'
```

When the header size is zero, or when the header is not on screen, calling `insertItemsAtIndexPaths` works fine. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

The class is a sub class of UICollectionViewController. Here is the code related to UICollectionView:

```
- (id)init {
  // Collection view layout
  UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
  layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
  layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320, 50); // Left for the switch
  layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;
  layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5;
  layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
  layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5);

  if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]) {
    // Collection view setup
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID"];
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -20, 320, 480-20-44-49);
    self.collectionView.backgroundView = nil;
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    ...
  }
  return self;
}
```

Then I implemented two delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [blogs count];
}
```

and

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewArg cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionViewArg dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  /* Some code to get blogView */
  [cell.contentView addSubview:blogView];
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is there said in log that the header cannot be nil.So give some valid input there and you can avoid the crash.

Like if the header section needs no input give it an view with clearclolor

For implementhing the header section you must implement the following datasource method

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Which delegate method should I use for that? Can you give me some example code? Thanks!

Comment: please put in you code ...may be i can point out what is missing

Comment: you should have added it in the Question itself.There is an edit option there :) Please follow the SO way

Comment: what is the purpose of providing layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320, 50);

Comment: layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeMake(320, 50); I want to leave some space on top of UICollectionView to add something else.